# Logging application block : database trace listener timestamp

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, logging-application-block

I'm logging exception using Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging Application Block.
I'm using the database trace listener.

Timestamp of the log entry is in UTC time by default.

I know I can have the timestamp of local time in the 'FormattedMessage' column of the 'Log' table by setting the log formatter like this :
    Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}

How can I do the same thing with the 'Timestamp' column ?

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to save local times in the database? Don't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to set the `Timestamp` property of the `LogEntry`.

E.g.:

```
LogEntry le = new LogEntry()
{
    Message = "Log it",
    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now // use local time
};

le.Categories.Add("General");

Logger.Write(le);
```

Other options to do what you want would be to create a Custom Trace Listener or to modify the `WriteLog` stored procedure to use any value you wish.  You could simply use `GETDATE()` or you could do some manipulation of the passed in UTC Timestamp:

```
DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), timestamp)
```

As a point of interest (since you wouldn't normally use this type of code), if you use the Write() method of the `FormattedDatabaseTraceListener` directly it uses the local DateTime.  E.g.:

```
var dbWriter = new FormattedDatabaseTraceListener(
    EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>(),
    "writeLog", "AddCategory", new TextFormatter());

dbWriter.Write("Log this!", "General");
```

But as a commenter wrote, I would recommend sticking with UTC.